# excel formula for searching a range of cells in an another range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need a formula for searching a range of cells in an another range of cells.

Please find sample data in image :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MATCH function:

```
B1 =IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,C$1:C$4,0)),"No","Yes")
```

Copy the formula down. You can adjust C$1:C$4 as needed.

From the example shown, I am assuming you need exact matches.

But if you want to return Yes, even if the cell is not an exact match as long as the string is found in the looked up array, you can use this:

```
B1 =IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&A1&"*",C:C,0)),"No","Yes")
```